# How to add a Pooling layer on a keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm loading a neural network using tensorflow and colab notbook from google. I removed the fully connected layer of the output layer and added another fully connected with only one neuron, and I freezed the other layer. I'm using `tf.keras.application.MobileNetV2` and I'm using the `mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs`. I want to train just this added output layer but I'm getting an 'error'. I guess is that I have to add a Pooling layer  using

My code is the following:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None , pooling='max', classes=2)
model.summary()
penultimate_layer = model.layers[-2]  # layer that you want to connect your new FC layer to 
new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(penultimate_layer.output) # create new FC layer and connect it to the rest of the model
new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.input, new_top_layer)  # define your new model


ultima_layer = new_model.layers[-1]
new_new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)


new_new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(new_model.input, new_new_top_layer)
```

Finally, to freeze the weights of all layers before the last one just did:

```
for layer in new_model.layers[:-2]:
    layer.trainable = False
new_model.layers[-1].trainable = True
```

For the training :

```
new_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = new_model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch = total_train // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_data = val_data_gen,
    validation_steps = total_val // batch_size
)
```

I'm getting the folloing error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-05a947aac1cd> in <module>()
      8 ultima_layer = new_model.layers[-1]
      9 new_new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)
---> 10 new_new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(new_model.input, new_new_top_layer)
     11 
     12 # tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)

5 frames

/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, processed_ops, created_layers)
    208     if getattr(tensor, '_keras_history', None) is not None:
    209       continue
--> 210     op = tensor.op  # The Op that created this Tensor.
    211     if op not in processed_ops:
    212       # Recursively set `_keras_history`.

AttributeError: 'AveragePooling2D' object has no attribute 'op'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might help.  I added the PoolingLayer before composing the new model like this and did not get the error you are seeing.  I hope this helps:

```
new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(penultimate_layer.output) # create new FC layer and connect it to the rest of the model
new_new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(new_top_layer)
new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=new_new_top_layer)  # define your new model
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `pooling='avg'` argument while instantiating `MobileNetV2` so that you get the globally average pooled value in the last layer (as your model exclude top layer). Since it's a binary classification problem your last/output layer should have a Dense layer with single node and sigmoid activation function. Therefore, you could add the last/output `Dense` layer with single node and feed the base model's output as follows.

```
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None , pooling='avg', classes=2)
# model.summary()
penultimate_layer = model.layers[-1]  # layer that you want to connect your new FC layer to
new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(penultimate_layer.output) # create new FC layer and connect it to the rest of the model
new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.input, new_top_layer)  # define your new model
print(new_model.summary())
```

Hope this will help.